# what is acting as the delegate? A view controller? 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I set a NSViewController's view as contentview of mainmenu's window,now how should i use `- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `NSWindowDelegate` to your .h file doesn't make the magic happen, you need to also set the delegate for your window.

[Here is Apple's documentation for setting a delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/delegate).

Comment: i set a NSViewController's view as contentview of mainmenu's window,now how should i set the delegate ?

Comment: you may want to edit your question to show more code; what is acting as the delegate?  A view controller?

Answer (score 0):

did you set the delegate of your window to your class?

and, in apple doc:

> Discussion This method may not always be called during window closing.
>   Specifically, this method is not called when a user quits an
>   application.